# How to implement network thread in qt

Tags: multithreading, qt

I am new to qt. 
I have an application with one thread that uses libevent loop. I wanted to add another network thread that sends out jobs as post requests via QNetworkAccessManager.

How can i implemet it?
Suppose , 
1. i have Obj that inherts QOBject (Inside i have QnetworkAccessmanager that sends requests)
2. My Thread class that inherits QThread and reimplements run method with its event loop
I wanted to send new jobs(requests) to the event loop of this MyThread how do i do that?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: Use signals and slots to send information from the main thread to the network thread and back.

Comment: Your questions seems to be overly general and ambiguous, and therefore unclear to me. It is unclear whether you are asking about communication between threads, how to do multi-threading in Qt, handling network communication, or a combination thereof.  I think you need to put some more work into design.  I suggest you clearly define the number of threads that you are using, what their life-cycle (how, why, when, and what are their conditions for being started and stopped) and what their purposes/roles are.